# Closures Inside Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js

Closures are functions that inherit variables from their enclosing environment. So lets see this code:

```
binaryServer = BinaryServer({port: 9001});

binaryServer.on('connection', function(client) {
  console.log("new connection");

  client.on('stream', function(stream, meta) {
    stream.on('data', function(data){
    //actions
    });
    stream.on('end', function() {
    //actions
    });
  });
});
```

So, I am correct if I say: " `function(data){//actions}` is a closure because inherits the variables of enclosing environment (like the object `client`) "? Because of my experiences that's what happening.

Comment: You might also hear that a function "closes over" a particular variable.

Comment: The usual JS `this` caveats apply, e.g., `this` in the closure won't be the `this` in its definition context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would be correct to say.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You are correct.

Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables. In other words, the function defined in the closure 'remembers' the environment in which it was created.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)